# Torque on a elementary magnetic dipole

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, magnetic-moment

Let's say I have a magnetic moment due dm due to electron spinning on its axis or orbiting around nucleus. B is the external magnetic field . Then torque on the moment will be dm x B . Now if I invoke a classic analogy of a small current loop with current I area A having effective moment dm (dm=IA) ,then the loop will experience Lorentz force on its dl element IdlxB and torque will be due to net affect of these Lorentz forces integrated over small elements.

Now as the loop rotates there would a extra velocity component of each element tangent to dl. So due to this velocity there would be extra Lorentz forces component opposing the flow of current.  This opposing force integrated over whole loop will add up to emf generated in loop which opposes the current.

Now come back to orginal magnetic dipole picture . Why there is no back emf in elementary magnetic dipole ( electron rotating around nucleus or spinning ) ? Or in other ways why there is no force opposing the electron's rotation ( because one component of Lorentz force will oppose the current in loop) ? So should the electron stop after some time ?

Comment: You are using $dm$ in a very imprecise manner, it is a differential and yet you've equated it to a quantity $IA$ which isn't a differential quantity.

Comment: @Triatticus  i agree ,i have written it in a very informal way . All i mean is just replacement of that small differential moment with a equivalent current carrying loop. If you want it in formal way consider dm= di*da . Any ways this doesn't change the overall question here. Why there is no back emf in this small loop (due to lorentz force )?